# Determine current MM periods?

Tags: abap, sap-erp

The standard SAP MM advice is that *only two periods can be open simultaneously*.

How to determine them from within the program (FM to call/table to read)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is stored in table **MARV**.

*(Answer [found on SDN](https://forums.sdn.sap.com:443/thread.jspa?threadID=1328780)).*

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to T code MMRV

2.Provide company code

you can find the current period , previous period and last period in previous year